A ring which is a sum of two proper right ideals
Assume that there exist two proper right ideals $A,B$ of a ring $R$ (with unity) such that $R=A+B$ and $R/A \cong R/B$ as right $R$-modules. Can we take $A,B$ principal? or does this imply that there exist two PRINCIPAL right ideals $aR,bR \subsetneqq R$ such that $R=aR+bR$ and $(R/aR)_R \cong (R/bR)_R$?

I edited the question.

Do you have any particular case in mind? IIRC the only way to have $R/A \cong R/B$ as modules is if $A = B$. So under your assumptions, $A = B = R = (1)$.

Of course not. Take the $R$-module $M=R \oplus R$. Notice that $M=(R \times 0) \oplus (0 \times R)$ so $0\times R \cong M/(R \times 0) \cong M/(0\times R) \cong R \times 0$ but $R \times 0 \neq 0 \times R$.

@HusseinEid Daniel Arreola is right, the trick is that he is talking about $R$-modules which are formed as quotients of $R$ by ideals, which $M = R \oplus R$ is not. See my comment for the argument.

@HusseinEid I mean an example of $R/A \cong R/B$ with $A \neq B$.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$, $A=(2,x)$ and $B=(2,1-x)$. Then $1=x+(1-x)\in A+B$, so $A+B=R$. On the other hand, $R/A=\mathbb{F}_2=R/B$.
Neither ideal is principal, since if $(2,x)=(f)$ then $f|2$ and $f|x$, so $f=1$. But $1\not \in(2,x)$. So $A$ is not principal. Neither is $B$ by a similar argument.

Excuse me. That is not related to my question. I asked if this implies (by somehow) that there exist principal right ideals $A,B$ of $R$ with the stated properties. Indeed, $A,B$ themselves need not be principal as your example shows.

$R/A \cong \mathbb{F}_2$ as rings or $R$-modules?. Is $\mathbb{F}_2$ a $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module?. Of course not.

$\mathbb{F}_2$ has a natural $\mathbb{Z}[x]$-module structure... This follows as $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x)$.

Here's the case of commutative rings (I have no idea in the non-commutative case):

Let $R$ be a ring with unit, $A$ and $B$ two ideals such that $R = A + B$ and such that there is a surjective map $\phi:R / A \rightarrow R/B$ of $R$-modules. Then $B=R$.

Indeed, precomposing $\phi$ with the quotient map $R \rightarrow R/A$, we find a surjection $R \rightarrow R/B$ of $R$-modules, whose kernel contains $A$ (because of the quotient map) and $B$ (because $B$ acts by $0$ on $R/B$ by the commutativity assumption), hence the kernel contains $A + B = R$. So the surjection is zero, hence $B = R$.
This implies in particular that the only way to find an isomorphism $R/A \cong R/B$ of $R$-modules, with $R = A + B$, is to have $A = B = R$. Moreover, the implied statement with principal ideals can never occur.
NB: there is a similar statement with $\phi$ injective, which I will let you prove in an analogous way.

This is not correct. There is no reason to say that the kernel of the composition $\phi\pi:R\to R/B$ contains $B$. Notice that the composition is not the usual canonical projection. Can you please provide steps for this particular issue?.

@HusseinEid The reason is quite simple: this is a morphism of left $R$-modules. Hence, if $b \in B$, we have $(\phi \circ \pi)(b) = (\phi \circ \pi)(b \cdot 1) = b \cdot (\phi \circ \pi)(1)$ (we view $b$ as $b \cdot 1$, $b$ in the ring $R$ acting on $1$ in the module R). Now, $(\phi \circ \pi)(1)$ is in the $R$-module $R/B$, a module on which $b \in B$ acts trivially (regardless of which element it acts on ; this is part of the $R$-module structure of $R/B$). Hence $b \cdot (\phi \circ \pi)(1)=0$.

Since $\phi\pi(1) \in R/B$, then $\phi\pi(1)=r+B$ for some $r\in R$. Since $R=A+B$, we can write $r=a+b'$ for some $a\in A; b'\in B$. Now, $\phi\pi(1)=a+B$. Hence, $b(\phi\pi(1))=ba+B$. How can $ba+B=0$ (or, equivalently, $ba\in B$)? (Unless $R$ is commutative. If $R$ is commutative, then $ba\in B$ so $ba+B=0$).

Your example is far from the stuitation we have here. Indeed, $n$ times anything in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ gives $0$ but $b$ times anything in $R/B$ does not give $0$!

@HusseinEid I see the mistake, indeed this works only in the commutative case. My apologies ! I have edited my answer.

Nevermind. Your effort is appreciated.
